# CSS: Dropdown menu gets hidden behind the content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please take a look at this [page](http://www.myquestweightloss.com/about-us/)

If you click on "Obesity Surgery", there is a drop down menu that is supposed to display. (It's using Twitter Bootstrap drop down menu).

I can confirm the menu is there, but it gets hidden behind the underlying content even though it has an absolute position with a high z-index.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Put `z-index: 99999;`

Comment: I tried adding a very high value for z-index, but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: @mdesdev's answer solved it for me! Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Obviously the problem lies with the z-index. But the problem is actually all the way up to the top parent. The header element with banner class has z-index: 1. Setting it to a higher number fixes the problem.

```
.banner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: 7 years after the fact: thank you! I was just fiddling around with the z-index of my submenu, but when I started taking the rest of the element-tree into account it started making more sense what I was doing!

Answer (score 2):

You should set the z-index:9999; of the menu element and its children to ensure that they are always on top.

You can play with the z-index of other elements to keep them above others on the page.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, with no luck.

Comment: that worked for me, but perhaps my master page was not as complicated.,

Answer (score 2):

Check if the overflow setting is set to hidden, if it is remove the value.

```
.banner {
    overflow: hidden // remove
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually due to the very top image (image of the clouds) being set with the position absolute and a high z-index. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following styles to class dropdown:

```
.dropdown {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```